# md-select append [object object] in body tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I ma a new bee in angular js, I was trying to create a select box using material angualr js but getting a bug i.e. as soon as I click on select box generated by md-select it appends [object Object] in body tag. could you please point out what I am doing wrong, or what could be the possible reason of this bug. following is my code.

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="select">
        <md-option ng-value="india">india</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="bangladesh">bangladesh</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="bhutan">bhutan</md-option>
        <md-option mg-value="nepal" >nepal</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

material is interfering with other framework. I experienced the same and I had to remove twitter bootstrap to make this working.

I found this one instance when I was calling AngularJs twice. Once I removed all. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.userState = 'india';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
  <div layout="row">
    <md-select ng-model="ctrl.userState">
      <md-option>
        <em>None</em>
      </md-option>
      <md-option value="india">india</md-option>
      <md-option value="bangladesh">bangladesh</md-option>
      <md-option value="bhutan">bhutan</md-option>
      <md-option value="nepal">nepal</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div layout="row">
    return value: {{ctrl.userState}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```